# Look for duplicate values in two different rows

Tags: database, excel, colors

I would like to search my Excel database of random people to find people who share last name & home address and are in my database (meaning people from same household), but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

So in Column `I`, I have last names of people in my database and in Column `K`, I have their address and I was wondering what code I could use so that Excel either colors values that are the same or gives me a `Yes` / `X` in Column M.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve your problem using pivot tables and concatenate function.

For example if you have a table like this one:

```
Name    Last Name   Address
-----------------------------
name0   lname0      address0
name1   lname0      address0
name3   lname3      address2
name4   lname3      address3
```

You can add one column and fill it with concatenate function. For example

=CONCATENATE(B2," ",C2)

result:

```
Name    Last Name   Address     concatenate(...)
-----------------------------------------------
name0   lname0      address0    lname0 address0
name1   lname0      address0    lname0 address0
name3   lname3      address2    lname3 address2
name4   lname3      address3    lname3 address3
name5   lname4      address3    lname4 address3
```

Then you can aggregate data automatically in a pivot table. An example of output would be

```
Row Elements       Name Count
-------------------------
lname0 address0    2
lname3 address2    1
lname3 address3    1
lname4 address3    1
```

You can find plenty of tutorials on-line about pivot tables.

Finally if you need more flexibility you need to create a script

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Concatenate function is exactly what I needed.